# Glittery smoke in render and viewport

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation, smoke-simulation

I'm rendering out this smoke sim and my smoke is glittery. Why?
My smoke's Resolution Division is 100 with a High Resolution Division of 2.
And it is a smoke sim based off of particles.
[image]

Here's a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P32WF.png) to the material node setup.

Comment: Do you have denoising turned on?

Comment: I've never really used that so I don't know where it is. :)

Comment: Denoising will just remove all definition of the smoke... you need to have more samples in the cycles render.

Comment: If you are in 2.8, it's in View Layer Context > Denoising. For 2.79, Render Layers > Denoising. Just click the checkbox. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think those are fireflies.  They are a common problem with blender.  Here's a link to help you reduce them.

https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies?rq=fireflies

Comment: Where is the "Multiple importance sample" setting for HDR's in blender 2.8? I think that may be the problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's on by default now.  Try clamping, or turning off caustics, although caustics are more realistic.